# Can't change scope variables value on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to edit scope variable value and I can't get it. Curiously, if I debug with console.log($scope), instead of $scope.subtotal, I've got all values also with ng-inspector Google extension.

Thank you a lot!

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('CartController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  function getSubtotalCart(){
    $.getJSON('/getSubtotalCart', function (response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == 'success') {
        $scope.subtotal = "Hello"; //response;
        $scope.$apply();
      } else {
        console.log(xhr);
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.getTotalCart = function(bool){
    console.log('Running');
    (bool) && getSubtotalCart();
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.subtotal);
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CartController" ng-init="getTotalCart(true)" ng-cloak></div>
```

Comment: If I declare $scope.subtotal outside of getJSON it's works.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use jQuery methods in AngularJS, I see that you are injecting $http is method would be appropriate

Comment: @Raxel21 can I use it synchronous mode? Using $http, I haven't got scope value yet outside of request

Answer (score 0):

You call `$scope.getTotalCart` inside `ng-init`. That makes it one of the first things it does as soon as it's called. In fact, it happens so quickly, that `/getSubcartTotal` hasn't even returned a value yet. That means that `$scope.subtotal` is still undefined. To fix this, you can give it an initial value of course, or you could delay the call to `getTotalCart` by placing it *inside* the response callback, or, if you're using `uiRouter`, you should be able to use ["resolve"](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to only load the controller *after* the request has completed.

Comment: Hello Ruben! I think my problem is: I can't to get scope variable out of JSON by async request.

Comment: You can, but only when the request is finished, and you don't know when that is. If you put `{{subtotal}}` inside the `<div>` it should show the new value. You can also use AngularJS' `$q` to wait for the request to complete